# Find number of functions $f$ which satisfy given conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\ln (x)$ denote the logarithm of $x$ with respect to the base
>   $e$. Let $S ⊂ \mathbb R$ be the set of all points where the function
>   $\ln(x^2 − 1)$ is well defined.
>
> Then the number of functions $f : S →\mathbb  R$ that are
>   differentiable, satisfy $f′(x) = \ln(x^2 − 1)$ for all $x ∈ S$ and
>   $f(2) = 0$ is
>
> - $0$
> - $1$
> - $2$
> - $\infty$

All I could make out was $S\in (\infty,-1) \cup (1,\infty)$. I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two solutions $f,g$ we have $(f-g)'\equiv 0$ which implies:
$$
f-g\equiv c_k
$$
on each interval $I_k$ they are defined on. The domain has two intervals $I_1=(-\infty,-1)$ and $I_2=(1,\infty)$. On $I_1$ you can choose any consant $c_1\in\mathbb R$ whereas you are forced to choose $c_2=0$ since:
$$
f(2)-g(2)=0-0=c_2
$$
Still, this gives you $\infty$ many solutions.

---

To be specific, define:
$$
q(x)=\int\ln(x^2-1) dx
$$
and use this to define:
$$
f_c(x)=
\begin{cases}
q(x)-q(2) & \qquad\text{for }x\in(1,\infty)\\
q(x)+c    & \qquad\text{for }x\in(-\infty,-1)
\end{cases}
$$
and you get an (uncountably) infinite family of solutions $\{f_c\}_{c\in\mathbb R}$. See the following graphs:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "..given two solution.." ?

Comment: @tatan: I mean "if you have two functions (not necessarily distinct) satisfying the conditions given in the problem". Then we analyze that to see where that leads.

Comment: Can you please check @Anon 's answer below and comment what is wrong in it?

Comment: @tatan: I commented on the other post + I added more details on my own post. Also I changed the names $f_1,f_2$ to $f,g$ to avoid confusion with the two intervals $I_1,I_2$ and their corresponding constants $c_1,c_2$. I hope it is clear. Not least from the animated GIF, where you can see some of the solutions in the infinite family and "check by eye" that they all solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks pretty obvious which makes me think I might be interpreting it wrong. Please do correct me in that case.

We have the equation:

$ f'(x) = ln(x^2-1) $

Integrating to get f(x),

$ f(x) = \int ln(x^2-1)dx $

Via integration by parts we get the solution,

$ f(x) = xln(x^2-1) - 2x + ln(\frac{x+1}{x-1}) + C $

where C is the constant of integration.

Using $ f(2) = 0 $, we arrive at a unique value of C. $ (4-3ln(3)) $

This implies there can be only one such function.

Comment: The answer given is $\infty$ so theres some error in your answer ;-)

Comment: This is what I first thought before thinking about the role the domain plays. Note that $f'\equiv 0$ only implies $f$ constant within each connected component. The same applies to the uniqueness of the integral. It only applies component wise.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. Thanks a lot!